# The best way to copy all cell contents between Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work with 2 Google spreadsheets which basically do the same thing but have different data in them so every time I make updates to one I have to make the same updates to the other. Sometimes the changes are complex so I thought I would automate the copying of changes from "Parent sheet" to child. This works by looking for the columns with the same names and moving them where they should be and also by replacing child formulas with parent formulas under the same headings, and finally copying data values in the child sheet to the new columns where they belong.

I've got to the point where this more or less works but the problem is copying the rest of the cell contents.

If I move data between sheets in a spreadsheet I can just copy source range to other range, but when moving data between spreadsheets, because there is no copyRangeBetweenSpreadsheets function I have to do move everything into variables. First formulas, then values, then data validation, then formatting and conditional formatting. It will get very slow and will eventually time out when the child spreadsheet gets big.

Is there a shortcut where I can load all the data into a single container to streamline the process?

Edited to add code. Here it is:

```
function updateChildSheets(){

  updateChildSheet('13_8O0xMjy_9KLGEWkfXpyIrG88bZ9Yr25eu7DRHC_V4','Links',1);

}

function updateChildSheet(childSID,sheet,ParentHeaderRow) {  //Parent Header row is the row containing the heading names for each column and is not necessarily thie first row of the sheet
                                                             //sheet is the sheet name inside the Parent and Child sheets to update
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parentSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  //var childSID = Browser.inputBox('Remote Sheet to Update');
  var childSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(childSID);
  var childSheet = childSS.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var childSheetMaxCols = childSheet.getMaxColumns();
  var childSheetMaxRows = childSheet.getMaxRows();
  var childSheetHeadings = childSheet.getRange(ParentHeaderRow+':'+ParentHeaderRow).getValues();
  var parentSheetHeadings = parentSheet.getRange(ParentHeaderRow+':'+ParentHeaderRow).getValues();
  var parentSheetMaxCols = parentSheet.getMaxColumns();
  var parentSheetMaxRows = parentSheet.getMaxRows();
  var parentSheetFormulas = parentSheet.getRange(1,1,parentSheetMaxRows,parentSheetMaxCols).getFormulas();
  var virtualSheetArr = [];

  //Create the new sheet headings
  var headingRow =[];

  for (var i in parentSheetHeadings[0]) headingRow.push(parentSheetHeadings[0][i]);
  // create the correct length (the number of rows in the child sheet)
  var dummyRow=[]; 
  virtualSheetArr.push(headingRow);

  //create empty rows equal to the length of data in child sheet
  for (var i in virtualSheetArr[0]) dummyRow.push('');
  for (var i=0; i<childSheetMaxRows-1; i++) {
    virtualSheetArr.push(dummyRow.slice())
  }
  //find childHeading and copy rows below into VirtualArr
  //for each column in source sheet
  Loop1:
  for (var headingCol=0; headingCol<virtualSheetArr[0].length; headingCol++){
    //Locate column in the child sheet (childSheetCol)
    var columnFound=false;
    for (var childSheetCol=0; childSheetCol<childSheetMaxCols; childSheetCol++){
      //if the column in child sheet matches the column in source sheet
      if (virtualSheetArr[0][headingCol] ==  childSheetHeadings[0][childSheetCol]) {
        columnFound=true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!columnFound) continue;

    //get both formulas and values from child sheet and save them to a 2D array using identical columns from the parent Sheet
    var childColValues = childSheet.getRange(1,childSheetCol+1,childSheetMaxRows,1).getValues();    
    var childColFormulas = childSheet.getRange(1,childSheetCol+1,childSheetMaxRows,1).getFormulas();
    for(var i=1; i<childColValues.length;i++){
      if(childColFormulas[i][0]!='') {   //If a parent cell comtains a formula, save the new parent formula to the target cell
        virtualSheetArr[i][headingCol] = parentSheetFormulas[i][headingCol];

        //if a cell contains Arrayformula() remove any values found below it
        if(/arrayformula/i.test(virtualSheetArr[i][headingCol])){ 
          for(var j=i+1; j<childColValues.length; j++){
            childColValues[j][0]='';
          }
        }
      }
      else if(childColValues[i][0]!='')  virtualSheetArr[i][headingCol] = childColValues[i][0];

    }
  }

  //Temporarily place the output in a test sheet to view output
  var testsheet = childSS.getSheetByName('testsheet');
  testsheet.clearContents().getRange(ParentHeaderRow,1,virtualSheetArr.length,(virtualSheetArr[0].length)).setValues(virtualSheetArr);
  if(ParentHeaderRow>1) {
    var parentSheetOtherHeadings = parentSheet.getRange(1+':'+(ParentHeaderRow-1))
    testsheet.getRange(1,1,parentSheetOtherHeadings.length,parentSheetOtherHeadings[0].length).setValues(parentSheetOtherHeadings);
  }

}
```

Comment: Let's see the code you're using, for at least part of this. Batch methods are not terribly slow

Comment: Ok I have added the code so you can see where I got so far. I tried adding in data validations but I removed it because it was too slow. To make it work on any pair of sheets you will only need to change the target sheet ID and the sheet name, and the header row for the child sheet in the top function: updateChildSheets. Each sheet should have columns with identical header names in the same row but they don't need to be in the same columns. Unknown columns in the child sheet will be ignored.